# Norm of columns in 3-dimentional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Given a numpy array `P` of shape `(n, m, m)` I want to get a numpy array `Q` of shape `(n, m)` where `Q[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(P[i][:,j])`. I have tried with `Q = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: np.linalg.norm(P[i][:,j]), (n, m), dtype=float)`, but I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I have a large array, so I looking for something with no significant time penalty.

Comment: Simply use it along the second axis : `np.linalg.norm(P,axis=1)`.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you!!